# Unable to push my app to bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I developed an app using watson and cloudant. Completed the coding part using eclipse. 
Build was successful and I got war file.
When I am trying to push this to bluemix, I am facing problem. 
on giving the command

`cf api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net 
or 
cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net`

I get the following in response

```
setting api endpoint to https://api.eu-gb.bluemixnet...
FAILED
Invalide SSL Cert for api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
TIP:Use 'CF api --skip--ssl-validation' to continue with an insecure API endpoint
```

Please help out, or tell some way to push my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why are you getting the SSL Cert error.

Will you please try and see if cf login works for you by giving it the endpoint directly ?
http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/whats-new-v6.html

-u is the Bluemix user-id and this will prompt you for password. Let me know if this resolves for you or you get the same SSL error

```
Example => 
    >>cf login -a api.ng.bluemix.net -u xxx@yy.zz -o xxx@yy.zz -s dev
    API endpoint: api.ng.bluemix.net
    Password>
    Authenticating...
    OK

    Targeted org xxx@yy.zz
    Targeted space dev

    API endpoint:   https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.14.0)
    User:           xxx@yy.zz
    Org:            xxx@yy.zz
    Space:          dev
```